# FlatMap vs Filter, Map Java

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a reason to use `.flatMap(...)` over a combination of `.filter(...)` and `.map(...)` for Java Streams?

Using `.flatMap(...)` can often be less readable than the combination of `.filter(...)` and `.map(...)`, so is there an advantage to using `.flatMap(...)`?

For instance with an `Optional`:

```
.flatMap(optional -> optional.isPresent() ? Stream.of(optional.get()) : Stream.empty())
```

or

```
.filter(optional -> optional.isPresent())
.map(optional -> optional.get())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I, along with the Java language architects, agree with you that `Stream#flatMap` for a `Stream<Optional<T>>` isn't readable in Java 8, which is why they introduced [`Optional#stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream()) in Java 9.

Using this, your code becomes much more readable:

```
.flatMap(Optional::stream)
```